# How can I have my template display a list on two different div tags without having redundancies

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a list from my Model but I want my template to display the list element in groups of  4 or half the total length of the list Example: let say i have 10 elements in my list i want 5 on the right size and 5 on the left side. Please see screenshot below.

This is how i want my page to look like:
[image: This is how i want my page to look like.]

But this is what i get:
[image: 2]

This is my HTML file.

```
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <p>hsjkhvdkdjhvjkdfnv kjdf, dfhvkhdnfvkjldf,xhvnkldsv.mckldfnv ,dfhxncjcshfxdjvhcnjsdnckndjvbc d,sxbc kjdjsxcbjdksbvc kjs,bhzscs,zhcnlksjhlnzcklsnzjcjsdzcjb ds
        cxdbjvcsdbzcjks,gdcbkjds,zbcn jkcdxbv,m dfxvchj bdxnvbjhdujxdnkck jdfvknc dfkjhvxjdknfxzjxvkc.
    </p>
  </div>
  

  {% for skill in skills_list%}  
 
  <div class="row skills-content">
   
    <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
      <div class="progress">
        <span class="skill">{{skill.skill_name}} <i class="val">{{skill.skill_value}}</i></span>
        <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{skill.skill_value}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  
  
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py:

```
#### TEST
class TestView(generic.ListView):
   model = Skills
   template_name = 'portfolio_app/test.html'


########################URL.py
from django.urls import path
from portfolio_app.models import *
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.fact,name='index'),
    #path('index/',views.SkillView.as_view,name='index'),
    path('about/',views.about_me,name='about'),
    path('service/',views.ServiceView.as_view(),name='service'),
    path('resume/',views.ResumeView.as_view(),name='resume'),
    path('contact/',views.ContactView.as_view(),name='contact'),
    path('test/',views.TestView.as_view(),name='test'),

]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) like this:

```
  <div class="row skills-content">
    <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
      {% for skill in skills_list|slice:":5" %}   
        <div class="progress">
        <span class="skill">{{skill.skill_name}} <i class="val">{{skill.skill_value}}</i></span>
        <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{skill.skill_value}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
     {% for skill in skills_list|slice:"5:" %}   
       <div class="progress">
        <span class="skill">{{skill.skill_name}} <i class="val">{{skill.skill_value}}</i></span>
        <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{skill.skill_value}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
       </div>
    {% endfor %}
   </div>
  </div>
```

To get rid of redundant div's create a separate template for skills and include that in you current template using include template tag like this:

skills.html:

```
<div class="progress">
   <span class="skill">{{skill.skill_name}} <i class="val">{{skill.skill_value}}</i></span>
     <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
       <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{skill.skill_value}} aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

your current temple:

```
  <div class="row skills-content">
    <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
     {% for skill in skills_list|slice:":5" %}
      {% include 'skills.html' with skill=skill %}
     {% endfor %}
   </div>
  </div>
```

similarly for second loop.

Comment: @Ahtisham Could you please explain the difference between 2 loops and 1 loop in this case?

Comment: the first loop only loop through the i believe the first 5 elements while the other one does the opposite

Comment: Your solution confused OP, so they came to the wrong conclusion. The issue was with the redundant last `</div>` and not splitting the `for` into two. Fix it, please.

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev The OP is using Bootstrap that follows grid system. Here OP wants to divided row into two columns. So there needs to be two div with `col-lg-6` class in order to create two colums  that is why two loops are needed.

Comment: @Ahtisham but you have 10 divs with `col-lg-6`, not 2. So there is no sense in 2 `for` loops in your answer.

Comment: @OleksiiTambovtsev Yes sorry my bad fixed that

Comment: I think now having 2 loops makes perfect sense

Comment: @Ahtisham try to replace them with one, and you will see that it works the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to move `<div class="row skills-content">` outside the `for` loop like this:

```
<div class="section-title">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <p>hsjkhvdkdjhvjkdfnv kjdf, dfhvkhdnfvkjldf,xhvnkldsv.mckldfnv ,dfhxncjcshfxdjvhcnjsdnckndjvbc
        d,sxbc kjdjsxcbjdksbvc kjs,bhzscs,zhcnlksjhlnzcklsnzjcjsdzcjb ds
        cxdbjvcsdbzcjks,gdcbkjds,zbcn jkcdxbv,m dfxvchj bdxnvbjhdujxdnkck jdfvknc
        dfkjhvxjdknfxzjxvkc.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="row skills-content">
    {% for skill in skills_list%}
    <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="fade-up">
        <div class="progress">
            <span class="skill">{{skill.skill_name}} <i class="val">{{skill.skill_value}}</i></span>
            <div class="progress-bar-wrap">
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow={{skill.skill_value}}
                     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And you should remove redundant last `</div>` to make it work correctly.

Comment: did not work i also  tried {% for skill in Skills| length >4 %} but it didnt work

Comment: I think your solution will also create 10 columns so what is the point ? I have fixed it in my solution

Comment: @Ahtisham The point is OP accepted your solution when you had 10 divs, so OP had two issues: `div.row` inside `for` and redundant last </div> (not splitting the for into two). I resolved the first problem in my answer and you accidentally resolved second.


PS. And I don't have 10 columns in my solution, 10 divs with `col-lg-6` in a row form 2 columns of 5 elements each.